# Use of colocate_with in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Is there another use of colocate_with in Keras? The Keras Model API code documented here: https://keras.io/models/model/ and here: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/models/Model results in a deprecation warning. The referenced code does not directly use colocate_with (though perhaps the API uses colocate_with). Will this Model API be deprecated or is the warning in error?

Example code from Keras documentation:

```
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Input, Dense

a = Input(shape=(32,))
b = Dense(32)(a)
model = Model(inputs=a, outputs=b)
```

Example code from TensorFlow documentation:

```
import tensorflow as tf

inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(3,))
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, activation=tf.nn.relu)(inputs)
outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(5, activation=tf.nn.softmax)(x)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
```

Both of these examples result in a deprecation warning:

```
...deprecation.py:323] From ~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/resource_variable_ops.py:435: colocate_with (from tensorflow.python.framework.ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Colocations handled automatically by placer.
```

This warning and use of colocate_with appears to be different than that referenced in "[What is colocate_with used for in tensorflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45341067/what-is-colocate-with-used-for-in-tensorflow)"

Will the documented method of using the Model API be deprecated? Will there be an alternative short of using a Sequential model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current master branch has yet to clean out the deprecated code. The nightly has already fixed a fair amount of these warnings, and it will take effect in the next release.

See this for more details:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/25996